# Android generate classes from java module

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `android` project and corresponding `plain java` module that is added as dependency. In `plain java` module I have some models for example

`data class Foo(val name:String)`

And what I would like to do is to create another model in my android project based on this `Foo` so for example

`data class FooAndroid(val name:String, val context:Context)`

At start I thought about writing `annotation processor` with custom `annotation` that is reachable inside `java` module, but then I would have to put `processor` in my `android module` to make those generated classes in android packages, but the problem is that `processor` does not find `annotated` classes from `plain java` module. (I have checked dagger and it also cant generate code for `Module` in modules without processor added as dependency.

Has anyone struggled with similar problem? Is it even possible in some way to auto-generate `android implementation` of `java model` from different module?

Comment: When you say "android" you actually mean "kotlin", right? Because you can write Apps for Android also in plain Java.

Comment: Right, the android module is written in `kotlin` it would be less problematic if it would require adding just additional fields ( like in the example) but there are also some android annotations that I would like to auto-generate